# Combine query_string and match together in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search a index in elastic search with the following body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "a*",
                        "default_operator": "AND"
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "country": "Spain"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "city": "Madrid"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

here is my indexed results:

```
 [
  {
    _id: "T__cU34BAF3zuzOUa7rD"
    _index: "es"
    _score: 1
    _source: {
      name: "Santiago",
      country: "Spain",
      city: "Madrid",
    }
    _type: "_doc"
  },
  ...
]
```

So this supposed to search for a word found in field `city` inside the `country`.

`country` and `city` are optional by the way and it should return all queries that start with `a` if `city` and `country` are empty.

Comment: Hi @Angels, could you add some examples of documents ?

Comment: And mappings please

Comment: I take the document from the DB which includes those fields that I just shared. I think I was not able to explain the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your problem, you want to return documents that have values that start with supposing `s`. And, along with this, the `country` and `city` conditions are optional.

You can combine query string and match query using the boolean query. Here `must` clause, works as a logical AND operator, and the `should` clause works as a logical OR operator.

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index Data:**

```
PUT <index-name>/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Santiago",
  "country": "Spain",
  "city": "Madrid"
}

PUT <index-name>/_doc/2
{
  "name": "San Franciscor",
  "country": "",
  "city": "Madrid"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "s*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "Spain"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "Madrid"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "<index-name>",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.4700036,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Santiago",
          "country" : "Spain",
          "city" : "Madrid"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "<index-name>",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.1823215,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "San Franciscor",
          "country" : "",
          "city" : "Madrid"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Angels its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have a new question could u please have a look when you had time please?